# Как сделать чтение и сохранение множества структур

Tags: c++, файлы, stl, fstream

Доброго времени суток, я начал изучать С++. У меня такой вопрос. Делаю справочник. Как реализовать его сохранение и чтение из файла. Сохранение получилось чисто в лоб, типа сделать текстовый файл из 5 контактов. Но мне нужно именно сохранение с последующим чтением из файла, чтобы этот справочник можно было пополнять новыми номерами. Тобишь получается как сделать чтение и сохранение контейнера множества структур. Как то так, спасибо.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct PhoneBook
{
    string Name;
    string Number;
    string Contact;

    PhoneBook (string& InputName, string& InputNumber)
    {
        Name = InputName;
        Number = InputNumber;
        Contact = (Name + " " + Number);
    }
    bool operator < (const PhoneBook& MatchName) const
    {
        return (Name < MatchName.Name);
    }
    operator const char*() const
    {
        return Contact.c_str();
    }
};


int main()
{
    set<PhoneBook> Contacts;

    ofstream SaveFile("PhoneBook.txt", ios::trunc);
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 5)
    {
        string Name, Number;
        cout << "Name: ";
        cin >> Name;
        cout << endl << "Number: " << endl;
        cin >> Number;
        Contacts.insert(PhoneBook(Name, Number));
        i++;
    };

    for(set<PhoneBook>::const_iterator iContact = Contacts.begin(); iContact != Contacts.end(); ++iContact)
    {
        SaveFile << *iContact << endl;
    }

    SaveFile.close();

    for(set<PhoneBook>::const_iterator iContact = Contacts.begin(); iContact != Contacts.end(); ++iContact)
    {
        cout << *iContact << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: JSON как формат хранения не рассматривали? К нему есть на практически все языки решения для чтения/записи.

Answer (score 2):

Я бы написал функции-члены записи в файл и чтения из файла, что-то типа

```
bool Phonebook::write(ostream&) const;
bool Phonebook::read(istream&);
```

В вашем варианте - с тремя строками - это может быть простая запись и чтение трех строк. Можно и бинарно. Функции должны указывать, все ли получилось.

Тогда и чтение, и запись выполняются одним циклом, типа

```
for(auto i: Contacts)
    if (!i.write(saveFile)) throw("Error saving phonebook");

PhoneBook p;
while(p.read(loadFile))
    Contacts.insert(p);
```

Дополняете - просто дописывая в конец файла...

Comment: Извини, так как я только учусь сразу не догоняю. В цикле записи , i это итератор по контейнеру Contacts, чтобы сохранить все существующие объекты структур PhoneBook??

Comment: Ну да, в цикле - это запись *всех* элементов. Главное, что я хотел донести - это то, что объект должен сам уметь себя записать и прочитать.